# Unable to get Facebook Open Graph meta tags to work in Sveltekit for routes other than home '/'

Tags: curl, frontend, svelte, sveltekit, share-open-graph

The Facebook meta tags work fine on the homepage and a preview is generated along with the `og:image`. However, when trying with individual blog article pages, the preview is not generated. `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/` is used for this testing.

When I try to navigate to routes such as `/blog` and `/blog/title`, the Facebook Open Graph Debugger does not see them. *(actual page data omitted for simplicity)*

The following is my `+page.svelte`:

```html
<!--src/routes/blog/[slug]/+page.svelte-->
<script>
    import { PUBLIC_API_URL } from '$env/static/public';
    import moment from 'moment';

    /** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
    export let data;
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My Blog" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<blog specific image>" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<blog url>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<short description>" />

    <title>Blog | Article title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="<short description>" />
</svelte:head>
```

The following is my `+page.server.js` for reference:

```js
// src/routes/blog/[slug]/+page.server.js

import { PUBLIC_API_URL } from '$env/static/public';

/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
export async function load({ fetch, params }) {
    const res = await fetch(`${PUBLIC_API_URL}/blog/${params.slug}`);
    const article = await res.json();
    return { article };
}
```

I have also tried locally with `cURL -I https://myurl.example`. The home `/` route returns:

```bash
HTTP/2 200
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-type: text/html
date: Fri, 16 Jun 2023 22:06:35 GMT
etag: "g9p070"
x-sveltekit-page: true
content-length: 132771
```

*(all the page HTML is returned when running without `-I` option)*

But the `/privacy-policy`, `/blog` and `/blog/[slug]` route returns:

```bash
HTTP/2 200
access-control-allow-origin: *
date: Fri, 16 Jun 2023 22:09:10 GMT
```

*(no output is shown when running without `-I` option)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Resolution

I found the solution by chance, while creating the reproduction for this issue.

I was using the handy [Svelte for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) extension in my original project to create routes.

I was selecting all the files by default, even-though some of them I did not intend to use as follows:

[image: Screenshot 2023-06-27 at 5 45 10 PM]

The particular file that was creating the issue was the default `+server.js` created by the extension. Contents as follows:

```js
// +server.js

/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
export async function GET() {
    return new Response();
};
```

While creating the reproduction I only created the necessary files manually and did not encounter the issue there.

Hence, removing the unused files from my original project solved it for me.

The [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) shows the expected output now.

I'm happy!